# Simulated device with Azure Function on IoT Hub is not able to trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-iot-hub

Currently I have simulated device that receives message from IoT Hub and processes it and after it is done, device sends message to IoT Hub. The device is working but it is running as .exe file on computer and Im trying to transform it and upload on Azure as function so I can avoid it not working when computer turns off or freezes while Im not around it.

---

I wanted to make it function triggered by events on IoT Hub but Im facing problem. Currently the function that sends message, sends it directly to device on IoTHub(my device) but in case like this, message is not "displayed" on IoT Hub so Im unable to use it as trigger. *I'm unable to change function that sends message to device.* Are there any options how to catch those messages on IoTHub or possibility to trigger it any other way?

Comment: Can you provide clarification on what the ask is. It is unclear whether you have succeeded in moving the simulated device code to an Azure function.
You might want to take a look at [Triggers on Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp) and look how to leverage [Azure IoT Hub Trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to send messages from Azure function to Azure IoT Hub. You can probably utilize [Device event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/device/send-device-event) Azure IoT Hub Rest API end point from the Azure Function and send the message to the Azure IoT Hub. Here is the request you can make to send the message to Azure IoT Hub.

```
POST https://fully-qualified-iothubname.azure-devices.net/devices/{id}/messages/events?api-version=2020-03-13
```

Please find the following reference to all the [Supported bindings for Azure Functions runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings?tabs=csharp#supported-bindings)

[image]

You can trigger the Azure Function by using the IoT Hub trigger. Refer the following resource that runs you through the steps needed to set up the [Azure IoT Hub trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-iot-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#example)